# How to write xpath in groovy for table dom

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, groovy, spock, geb

[image: HTML snippet]

How to write XPath for above table 2nd row in Groovy (Geb and Spock framework)?

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask). BTW, xpath is language agnostic, should work on almost any having xpath implementation. Also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I edited your question, making the inline screenshot visible. Please learn about basic markdown formatting syntax, and also give your questions some more love in the future. Spelling, punctuation and formatting might feel unimportant to you, but they help others to understand others to better understand your question. Sloppy questions yield either sloppy answers or none at all. "Garbage in, garbage out", as the saying goes. Please also do not paste screenshots of code but the actual code, nicely formatted in a code block. Then someone can copy your sample code and reproduce the problem.

Comment: As for your two Geb questions here, I warmly recommend the wonderful [Book of Geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/) and the [Spock manual](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.2-M1/all_in_one.html). They are valuable sources of information for basic questions like yours.

Answer (score 0):

In Geb, usually we use CSS selectors rather than XPath in order to match DOM elements, even though, if you insist, a Selenium-like `By.xpath` is certainly possible.

How about one of these, depending on how specific you want to be?

```java
$("tr", 1)                // 2nd row of any table on the page
$("table", 0).$("tr", 1)  // 2nd row of 1st table on the page
```

See e.g. "Book of Geb" chapters

- [The jQuery-ish navigator API](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#the-jquery-ish-navigator-api)
- [Finding & filtering](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#finding-and-filtering)

Please do learn Spock and Geb basics. Stack Overflow is not a place for people who are too lazy to read manuals, only for developers who have done so, but still having concrete problems, presenting them in a reproducible way and clearly describing what they tried and how the actual result differs from the expectation. This was your free shot, because you are new here and we welcome newbies.